# Which are possible verbs to refer to someone that walks using walking sticks?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I believe "to walk" is okay, but I want to know if there are other verbs (non-derogatory) more acceptable for people that use walking sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word that springs to my mind is ***hobble***, which means:

> **hobble** (*verb*) walk in an awkward way, typically because of pain from an injury: *he was hobbling around on crutches*.

The word doesn't necessarily have negative connotations; here is an excerpt where it was used in a [2011 news story](http://www.politico.com/story/2011/01/boehner-this-is-the-peoples-house-047078) (emphasis added):

> In another conciliatory note, Rep. John Dingell (D-Mich.), the “dean of the House” and longest-serving House member in history, swore Boehner in as speaker at 2:15 p.m. Wednesday. A moment later, Dingell **hobbled with his cane** to the Speaker’s desk to congratulate Boehner.